# Nokogiri XML: trying to move image url from element to attribute

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to move a large number of urls (580) from inside the image element to being within the quote marks of the image element's url attribute in my XML document.

Here is an example:

What I have at the moment:

```
<image type="photo" url="">http://contentadmin.livebookings.com/dynamaster/image_archive/original/f24c60a52e7ac0874be57e51bce30726.jpg</image>
```

What I want to change it to:

```
<image type="photo" url="http://contentadmin.livebookings.com/dynamaster/image_archive/original/f24c60a52e7ac0874be57e51bce30726.jpg"></image>
```

I have looked closely at the Nokogiri documentation under their modifying section here: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html but they don't deal specifically with attributes.

I've also studied this previous Stack Overflow question: [Setting an attribute in a Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419808/setting-an-attribute-in-a-nokogirixmlnodeset-with-css)

I've tried quite a few different variations based on my research on Nokogiri, below is my latest attempt: (not sure if I am using "each" properly here. I am css selectors with Nokogiri as this seems to be more straightforward for me than xpath which is a bit more advanced.

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.read('xml-output-no-error-version.xml')

doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

actual_links = doc.css('image').text

link_elements = doc.css('image')

link_attributes = link_elements["url"]

actual_links.each do |l|
  l.link_attributes
end

File.write('new-xml-output.xml', doc.to_xml)
```

I get this error in the console:

```
ruby nokogiri.rb
nokogiri.rb:11:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from nokogiri.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Here is a more complete snippet from my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listings>
<language>en</language>
<listing>
<id>43927</id>
<cell1>Andover House</cell1>
<cell2>28-30 Camperdown</cell2>
<cell3>Great Yarmouth</cell3>
<cell4>NR30 3JB</cell4>
<cell5>GB</cell5>
<cell6>52.6003767</cell6>
<cell7>1.7339649</cell7>
<cell8>+44 1493843490</cell8>
<category>Restaurants - British</category>
<image type="photo" url="">http://contentadmin.livebookings.com/dynamaster/image_archive/original/f24c60a52e7ac0874be57e51bce30726.jpg</image>
<cell11>http://www.bookatable.co.uk/andover-house-great-yarmouth-norfolk
</cell11>
</listing>
...
</listings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me:

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.read('xml-output-no-error-version.xml')

doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

link_elements = doc.css('image')

link_elements.each do |l|
  l['url'] = l.text
  l.content = ''
end

File.write('new-xml-output.xml', doc.to_xml)
```

Very briefly the call to `css` returns an array of Nokogiri elements that need to be modified individually by setting the attribute `url` to the value of the `text`, and then by wiping out the `content` of the element. Note that you read the value using `text` and you set it using `content`.

Comment: Beautiful! Worked perfectly thanks Marco! Where can I read more about this in the documentation? (teach a man how to fish etc etc)

Comment: I had used Nokogiri before, so I didn't need to look it up, but the tutorials section in the nokogiri official site  [here](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/) is a good start.

Comment: thanks Marco, that was one of my main ports of call, also the Nokogiri section of the "Bastards Book of Ruby" was really, really helpful for me as a relative "beginner": http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/toc/

Comment: You can retrieve the "text" using either `text` or `content`. If the content of the node happens to be another node you'll get everything, whereas `text` will only return the text node(s). If that sub-node happens to be a text node there's no difference. Knowing why and when we use one or the other is important.